# Scala - extracting fields from the value part of key-value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below data obtained after performing a join and I need to extract few fields from the value part of the key-value pair. Please help me how to reference the value part and then the fields in it.

```
res0: Array[(String, (String, Int))] = Array((48180,(48180,2012-12-01 20:24:34.0,2014-01-18 21:11:03.0,David,Baird,4429 Hazelwood Avenue,Santa Ana,CA,92719,6579627835,2014-03-18 13:31:18.0,2014-03-18 13:31:18.0,2)),
(23136,(23136,2011-05-13 04:15:05.0,2012-12-28 02:52:19.0,Shirley,Ayers,792 Parkway Street,Pendleton,OR,97877,5412977058,2014-03-18 13:30:29.0,2014-03-18 13:30:29.0,2)))
```

expected output: first, last, 4th and 5th fields from the value part.

```
48180 2 David Baird
23136 2 Shirley Ayers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation you can solve like this:

```
rdd.map { case (k, v) => (k, v._13, v._4, v._5) }
```

But, according what I see you have a greater issue, your value is not a tuple of 13 positions, is a tuple of two positions. The first is a string and the seccond is a Integer. If this is the true situation you can do like this:

```
rdd.map { case (k, v) => (k, v._2, v._1.split(',')(3), v._1.split(',')(3)) }
```